# I'm getting `failed to copy: local error: tls: bad record MAC` error when I build node container for `React-app` in docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, dockerfile

My os details:
windows 10
Version 22H2 (OS Build 19045.2728)

My Dockerfile:

```
# pull the base image
FROM node:lts-alpine

# set the working direction
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./


RUN npm install


# add app
COPY . ./

EXPOSE 3000

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "devServer": {
    "allowedHosts": [
      "localhost",
      "127.0.0.1"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.11",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "fsevents": "^2.1.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-auth-kit": "^2.8.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-persist": "^1.0.2",
    "react-rating-stars-component": "^2.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.6",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

My try:

1. First I changed the base image to `node:14-apline` and `node:slim` but it was not working,That time I'm getting new error.
   error:
   #10 23.37 npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2. I tried to restart the docker in powershell.

The main error:

```
=> ERROR [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:lts-alpine@sha256:ffc770cdc09c9e83cccd99d663bb6ed56cfaa1bab94baf1b12b626aebeca9c1  218.1s 
=> => resolve docker.io/library/node:lts-alpine@sha256:ffc770cdc09c9e83cccd99d663bb6ed56cfaa1bab94baf1b12b626aebeca9c10         0.0s 
=> => sha256:ffc770cdc09c9e83cccd99d663bb6ed56cfaa1bab94baf1b12b626aebeca9c10 1.43kB / 1.43kB                                   0.0s 
=> => sha256:19eaf41f3b8c2ac2f609ac8103f9246a6a6d46716cdbe49103fdb116e55ff0cc 1.16kB / 1.16kB                                   0.0s 
=> => sha256:f520ad35ba68f1ed1301a5eda87eaa722e468a9fc3a179868a035dc4c5dddaef 6.48kB / 6.48kB                                   0.0s 
=> => sha256:63b65145d645c1250c391b2d16ebe53b3747c295ca8ba2fcb6b0cf064a4dc21c 3.37MB / 3.37MB                                  15.7s 
=> => sha256:f41005eb563ce84e6c742a787d6a598fde273c134e94c90acc6115853a7f8315 10.49MB / 47.54MB                               218.1s 
=> => sha256:69dcb013f10fed3864b0f9915d6721b09f0c6717e5452ee96e04fde6082322a7 2.35MB / 2.35MB                                  13.1s 
=> => sha256:00a00d31565028f3c00c64959dafe4587320e8c99a39982ccda8a8a9ccef7123 449B / 449B                                      15.3s 
=> => extracting sha256:63b65145d645c1250c391b2d16ebe53b3747c295ca8ba2fcb6b0cf064a4dc21c                                        0.2s 
------
> [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:lts-alpine@sha256:ffc770cdc09c9e83cccd99d663bb6ed56cfaa1bab94baf1b12b626aebeca9c10:
------
failed to copy: local error: tls: bad record MAC
```